# Accessing objects in a Form Load Event?

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Im making a beat pad in a windows forms c++/CLI application.

How do I access objects that are in the `Form1_Load` event?

```
public:
    System::Void Form1_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        System::Windows::Media::MediaPlayer^ cymbal
            = gcnew System::Windows::Media::MediaPlayer();
        cymbal->Open(gcnew System::Uri("wav file directory"));
    }
private:
    System::Void button1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender,
            System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e) {
        if(e->KeyCode == Keys::R)
            cymbal->Play();
    }
```

The error produced is that `cymbal` is an undeclared identifier.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a scope to the handle. if your class name is `MyClass`
then this should be the handle's signature:

```
System::Void MyClass::button1_KeyDown(System::Object^  sender, System::Windows::Forms::KeyEventArgs^  e)
```